# Build your entire UI with HTML

Tags: html, r, shiny

I went through the tutorial located at http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html but sadly, it's not working the way it is suppose to.

I ran the code below in RStudio and I can see it is working fine on my browser.

```
library(shiny)
runExample("08_html")
```

However, the index.html isn't getting generated. I don't see any `www`. I see only these two files `server.R` and `ui.R` in the folder. What am I doing wrong?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial on [http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html)  it seems to work.

So, in Rstudio start with creating a new Shiny Web App from the File>New File menu.

Provide a name for your app.

Go the files window in Rstudio, you should now see a folder with the name of your app and an ui.R and server.R file

**Delete ui.R and create a folder www.**  It is something you have to do yourself.

Create the index.html files as per the tutorial. Save it in the www folder.

To run your app, open the server.R in Rstudio you should see the Run App button and should be able to run the app.